# G++-4.9 Link Error When Compiling With Makefile Instead of Xcode on OSX

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile, linker, gcc4.9

I have a C++ library project that I have been working on for a while now that I have been writing from the comfort of Xcode. I Decided to get the project set up to compile using make so that it will be easier to distribute when the time comes. The project has around 40 headers and 30 .cpp files right now.

The error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<DSG::SignalProcess*, std::__1::allocator<DSG::SignalProcess*> >::__push_back_slow_path<DSG::SignalProcess* const&>(DSG::SignalProcess* const&) in AudioSettings.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [lib/DSG.dylib] Error 1
```

The Makefile:

```
.PHONY : clean install

CC = g++-4.9
CPPFLAGS= -fPIC -g -std=gnu++11 -Os -Wall -I/usr/local/include 
LDFLAGS= -dynamiclib 


SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
HEADERS = $(wildcard src/*.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

DSG_LIBDIR = lib

DSG_HEADERINSTALLDIR = /usr/local/include/DSG
DSG_LIBINSTALLDIR = /usr/local/lib

TARGET=$(DSG_LIBDIR)/DSG.dylib

all: $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

install: 
    cp -f $(TARGET) $(DSG_LIBINSTALLDIR) 
    mkdir -p $(DSG_HEADERINSTALLDIR)
    cp -f $(HEADERS) $(DSG_HEADERINSTALLDIR)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

The Header:

```
#ifndef __DSG__AudioSettings__
#define __DSG__AudioSettings__
#include <vector>
#include "DSGTypes.h"
namespace DSG {
    class SignalProcess;
    /*!\brief DSG::AudioSettings - Global Storage For Audio Settings Such As Sample Rate
     */
    class AudioSettings{
    public:
        static DSG::DSGFrequency const& SampleRate();
        static DSG::DSGFrequency const& SampleRate(DSG::DSGFrequency const& value);
        static DSG::DSGFrequency const& Nyquist();
        static bool AddSampleRateListener(SignalProcess* listener);
        static bool const& IsSampleRateSet();
    protected:
        static DSG::DSGFrequency _sampleRate;
        static DSG::DSGFrequency _nyquist;
        static std::vector<DSG::SignalProcess*> _listeners;
        static bool _set;
    };
    namespace{
#define SampleRateDefault 44100//hidden macro defining default sample rate
    }
    //!\brief DSG::SampleRate - Get Global Sample Rate
    inline DSG::DSGFrequency const& SampleRate(){
        return DSG::AudioSettings::SampleRate();
    }
    //!\brief DSG::SampleRate - Set Global Sample Rate
    inline DSG::DSGFrequency const& SampleRate(DSG::DSGFrequency const& value){
        return DSG::AudioSettings::SampleRate(value);
    }
    //!\brief DSG::Nyquist() - Pre-Calculated Nyquist Limit. Use instead of calculating each time needed. This value will be updated whenever the sample rate changes.
    inline DSG::DSGFrequency Nyquist(){
        return DSG::AudioSettings::Nyquist();
    }
    //!\brief DSG::AddSampleRateListener() - Allows Generators to be notified if the sample rate changes
    inline bool AddSampleRateListener(DSG::SignalProcess* listner){
        return AudioSettings::AddSampleRateListener(listner);
    }
    //!\brief DSG::VerifySampleRateSet() - Allows a Generator to ask if a valid sample rate has been set
    inline void VerifySampleRateSet(){
        if (!DSG::AudioSettings::IsSampleRateSet()) {
            SampleRate(SampleRateDefault);
        }
    }
}
#endif /* defined(__DSG__AudioSettings__) */
```

And the .cpp:

```
#include "AudioSettings.h"
#include "SignalProcess.h"
DSG::DSGFrequency DSG::AudioSettings::_sampleRate;
DSG::DSGFrequency DSG::AudioSettings::_nyquist;
bool DSG::AudioSettings::_set=false;
std::vector<DSG::SignalProcess*> DSG::AudioSettings::_listeners;
DSG::DSGFrequency const& DSG::AudioSettings::SampleRate(){
    return _sampleRate;
}
DSG::DSGFrequency const& DSG::AudioSettings::SampleRate(DSG::DSGFrequency const& value){
    if (!_set) {
        _set=true;
    }
    _sampleRate = value;
    _nyquist = _sampleRate*0.5;
    for (auto i:_listeners) {
        i->SampleRateChanged(_sampleRate);
    }
    return _sampleRate;
}
DSG::DSGFrequency const& DSG::AudioSettings::Nyquist(){
    return _nyquist;
}
bool DSG::AudioSettings::AddSampleRateListener(DSG::SignalProcess* listener){
    _listeners.push_back(listener);
    return true;
}
bool const& DSG::AudioSettings::IsSampleRateSet(){
    return _set;
}
```

The code above is the source file the linker is saying that it can find a symbol from.

The problem is that I can compile and link this source into the library using Xcode but not with the makefile. So i fear that I have messed the makefile up somehow. I am using the exact same compiler, GCC 4.9.2 in both cases so i think it is a matter of compiler and linker commands differing between Xcode and the makefile.

I need to know what to change to get it to link? If there is any more info that I can provide please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Are there object files left over from xcode? It looks to me like a part of them expects to be linked against libc++, and that gcc tries to link them to libstdc++.

Comment: @Wintermute The object files from Xcode are in a completely different file structure from the ones i am using for make. Everything is completely separated. What do you suggest? what linker options can i set to adjust that?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to change a linker or a compiler option. The basic problem is (probably) that there are two implementations of the C++ standard library in MacOS X (libc++ from clang/llvm and libstdc++ from GNU), and the error you get makes sense if the code was compiled with the libc++ headers and is linked against libstdc++ -- __vector_base_common exists in libc++ but not in libstdc++. Can you compile it with clang++ instead of g++, possibly with the parameter `-stdlib=libc++` and see if that changes things?

Comment: @Wintermute I could compile it with clang if it comes down to it but that would be a last resort for me because of the realtime nature of the code. Gcc has been producing much faster code so far. I have been compiling with gcc in xcode, I have a patch that lets me use gcc in xcode 6 and it has worked so far. What can I dro to get it to compile with libstdc++ so that the linked doesn't look for the wrong vector implementation symbols?

Comment: You have to make gcc use the libstdc++ headers during the compilation stage to make it linkable with libstdc++. Why it doesn't do that automatically is the puzzling part. There doesn't happen to be a copy of the libc++ headers in `/usr/local/include`, does there? Alternatively, you could convince gcc to link to libc++ instead of libstdc++. Passing `-lc++` might work, although that's really hackish. You might have to use `gcc` instead of `g++` to link in that case.